# how can i load an Image to TImage from a resource using FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is it possible to load a bitmap from a resource in fire monkey?
like this

```
Var
  MyImage:TImage;
Begin
  MyImage:=TImage.Create(Self);
  MyImage.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'Image');
```

but TImage hasn't  LoadFromResourceName Methode.
is any way to do that?
thanks